# OnClickListener super

Tags: java, android

Why can I not pass `this` as Context in following code?
I am getting error

`The constructor DataManager(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined`

I am new to android programming, so sorry if question is weird!!

Any help would be great.

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.d("vkx", "clk insert");
String qq="insert into users(id,name,password) values ('6','usrs','passs')";
            DataManager dm=new DataManager(this);
            dm.SqliteExecutenonquery(qq);

            Log.d("vkx", "clk insert done");
        }
    });
```

I have my `DataManger` class

```
        public DataManager(Context cont) {
    super(cont, DBname, null, DBver);
}
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you are doing is when instantiating DataManager, You are not passing a context as a paramater but actually your instance of OnClickListener.

```
DataManager dm=new DataManager(YOUR_CLASS_NAME.this);
```

YOUR_CLASS_NAME should be the Activity class name. ie

```
class MyClass extends Activity{

  public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
           DataManager dm=new DataManager(MyClass.this);

        }
    });

  }
}
```

Give this a try and let me know how it goes

Comment: Great,,,
m loving SO so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have written anonymous class `new OnClickListener() {`

There is no constructor for `DataManager` class with `OnClickListener` as type parameter.

I think instead of `this`, you need use `getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 0):

"this" is a reference to the current instance of the containing class.

Where you have used "this", it refers to an instance of an anonymous inner class of type onClickListener.

I believe that you might be wanting to pass the context of the Activity defining the onClickListener?  If so, use `MyActivity.this`, where MyActivity is the name of the Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Just write `MyClassName.this`, assuming that 'MyClassName' is the Name of your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

before `setOnClickListener` add this line:

```
final Context ThisContext = this;
```

and in your listener use this

```
DataManager dm=new DataManager(ThisContext);
```